# Connect database with MyBatis without xml file

Tags: java, database-connection, mybatis

I am  trying to connect a small java application with a database using MyBatis.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:xxxx:xxxx"/>
                <property name="username" value="xxxxx"/>
                <property name="password" value="xxxxx"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="xml/Mapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Before, I got the session as follows

```
String resource = "Configuration.xml";
SqlSession session = null;
try{
    Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
    SqlSessionFactory sqlMapper = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader); 
    session = sqlMapper.openSession();
```

I want to connect to the database without the use of xml file. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked MyBatis 3 user guide? There is a section called "Building SqlSessionFactory
without XML". Also there is no need to use XML based mapping, you could use annotation based statement mapping and avoid XML configuration altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.Environment;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.apache.ibatis.transaction.TransactionFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory;


String user = "xxxxx";
String password = "xxxxx";
String databasenameURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:xxxx:xxxx";
String dbDriver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";


DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource(
        dbDriver, databasenameURL, user, password);
TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
Environment environment = new Environment("development",
        transactionFactory, dataSource);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder()
        .build(configuration);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe its late, but for future readers.

you can parse the xml to string and modify any value you want later.:

this worked for me:

```
    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.apache.commons.io.input.CharSequenceReader;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
    import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
    import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
    import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Reader;

    public class MySqlSessionFactory
    {
        private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MySqlSessionFactory.class);
        private static SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory()
        {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        /**
         * Initialize SqlSessionFactory instance, to be used later in all the project
         *
         * @return boolean if sqlSessionFactory is build
         */
        public static boolean initializeMySqlSessionFactory() throws IOException
        {
            log.trace("Enter method initializeMySqlSessionFactory.");
            String resource = "mybatis-config.xml";
            boolean result;
            Reader reader = null;
            Reader parsedReader = null;
            try
            {
                reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
                String parsedXMLConfig = IOUtils.toString(reader);

                parsedXMLConfig = StringUtils.replace(parsedXMLConfig, "${jdbcUrl}", "databaseURL");
                parsedXMLConfig = StringUtils.replace(parsedXMLConfig, "${username}", "databaseUser");
                parsedXMLConfig = StringUtils.replace(parsedXMLConfig, "${password}", "databasePassword");
                parsedReader = new CharSequenceReader(parsedXMLConfig);

                sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(parsedReader);
                result = true;
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                result = false;
                log.error("Error calling initializeMySqlSessionFactory.", e);
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
            finally
            {

                if(reader != null )
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
                if(parsedReader != null )
                {
                    parsedReader.close();
                }

            }
            log.trace("Exit method initializeMySqlSessionFactory. Method result: " + result);
            return result;
        }

    }
```

also with this way, you can change any specified field you want... and pay attention to put the same placeholder in the xml file (${jdbcUrl}, ${username}, ${password})